# Re-publishing Content Types from the Hub

Tags: 2013, content-type, content-type-hub

I have a Content Type Hub and four consuming sites, two years ago we successfully published content types to these sites, we then made some changes to the content types at library/list level (depending on the needs of that library/list/Site).  My client would now like to add new consuming sites, using the same content types.  Is it possible to re-publish the content types to the new consuming sites, and not to the original four sites?

My concern is that the changes we've made to the content types at library/list level will be erased (in the original consuming sites), when the content types are re-published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my new test environment I've recreated the same scenario as mentioned above, what I found was, when I created the new Site Collection the site inherited all of the content types that have already been publish. There's no need to re-publish content types for the new site collection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you would need to re-publish the content types.

After you have created the new site collections, you can tell them to consume content types from the content hub by clicking Settings cog -> Site Settings -> Content Type Publishing.

Then tick the 'Refresh all published content types on next update' checkbox and hit OK.

This will mean that your existing sites will remain unaffected. And your new sites will pick up the content types as they are in the content hub.

Comment: On my new test environment I've recreated the scenario, what I found was: